# How to highlight and edit the row (like iCal in SnowLeopard ) in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I would like to implement similar to iCal implementation. I want to highlight and edit the row at the same time. I have used cellBased tableview. I tried the following things.

```
 [self.tableView editColumn:0 row:[self.array count]-1 withEvent:nil select:YES];
 NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.array count]-1 ];
 [self.tableView selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:YES];
```

But above code highlights all the rows but not the current row. I want to highlight the current row and want to edit the same. Any hints to accomplish this?

---

I would like to implement some thing similar to **Mail**. When clicked on item,the row should get highlighted and the textField should get highlighted. I don't need an icon on the left side.

Comment: Why are you passing `YES` for `byExtendingSelection:`? Have you tried `NO`?

Comment: @Ken Thomases I tried with NO,but it will not highlight the row.

Comment: Maybe I'm forgetting something... but isn't clicking and highlighting default behavior?

Comment: @Vervious :  It is the default behavior.I need to customize the cell as the entire row is occupied by textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Customized the TableViewCell and implemented the drawWithFrame.

-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView
{
    NSRect newFrame = cellFrame;
    newFrame.origin.x += 50;
    newFrame.origin.y += 2;
    newFrame.size.height -=4;
    [super drawWithFrame:newFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

Following link helped me in resolving the issue.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html